# How to copy an Excel worksheet to an e-mail body with formatting?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, visual-studio-2013, html-email

I am creating a console application on a server, that will copy the contents of a MS Excel file (with colors and formatting) to the body of an e-mail. I am not trying to attach the worksheet, but simply copy it so that when the business users view the e-mail on their phone/tablet/device, they don't need the Excel application installed to view the report.

I need help in figuring out how to copy and display the worksheet in the body of the email.

Currently I have the following, but it only copies the actual string data, not any pretty formatting:

```
public static void pullDataFromExcel(string fileName)
{
    string mySheetPath = @"C:\Users\lmilligan\Downloads\";
    MSExcel.Application excelApp = new MSExcel.Application();
    excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
    excelApp.Visible = true;
    MSExcel.Workbook book = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(mySheetPath + fileName);
    MSExcel.Worksheet sheet = book.ActiveSheet;
    book.RefreshAll();
    var data = "";
    foreach (MSExcel.Range row in sheet.UsedRange.Rows)
    {
        foreach (MSExcel.Range cell in row.Columns)
        {
            data += cell.Value + "  ";
        }
        data += "\n";
    }
    MSOutlook.Application olApp = new MSOutlook.Application();
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("email@myServer.com", "thisIsMe@myServer.com");
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    client.Port = 25;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Host = "mail.myServer.net";
    mail.Subject = "AutoMailer test";
    mail.Body = Convert.ToString(sheet);
    client.Send(mail);

    book.Save();
    book.Close();
    excelApp.Quit();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    pullDataFromExcel("mySheet.xlsx");

}
```

Comment: Does it need to be in the body? It might be more _user friendly_ as an attachment?

Comment: You could present the data in a HTML table to have excel-like formatting.

Comment: Yes Christiandev it has to be in the body so that when the business users view the report on their mobile device, they don't need Excel installed.

Comment: What about pdf? You could format the data as you wanted, and the user would be able to view it exactly as you intended. Obvioulsly a bit more work to develop, but a much better 'experience' for the user.

Comment: .PDF would work - the issue is having the Excel report as the body of the e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact answer you're looking for, but if you can live with a PDF attachment then I've used something similar to this before to export the active sheet as a PDF file including the formatting:

```
Sub PDFMail()
  Dim IsCreated As Boolean
  Dim i As Long
  Dim PdfFile As String
  Dim OutlApp As Object

  ' Define PDF filename
  PdfFile = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  i = InStrRev(PdfFile, ".")
  If i > 1 Then PdfFile = Left(PdfFile, i - 1)
  PdfFile = PdfFile & FName & ".pdf"

  ' Export activesheet as PDF
  With ActiveSheet
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PdfFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
  End With

  ' Use already open Outlook if possible
  On Error Resume Next
  Set OutlApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If Err Then
    Set OutlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    IsCreated = True
  End If
  OutlApp.Visible = True
  On Error GoTo 0


  ' Prepare e-mail with PDF attachment
  With OutlApp.CreateItem(0)

    ' Prepare e-mail
    .Subject = "SUBJECT HERE"
    .To = "TO HERE"
    .CC = "CC HERE
    .BCC = "BCC HERE"
    .Body = "BODY TEXT HERE"
    .Attachments.Add PdfFile

    ' Try to send
    On Error Resume Next
    .Send
    Application.Visible = True
    If Err Then
      MsgBox "E-mail was not sent", vbExclamation
    Else
      MsgBox "E-mail successfully sent", vbInformation
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

  End With

  ' Delete PDF file
  Kill PdfFile

  ' Quit Outlook if it was created by this code
  If IsCreated Then OutlApp.Quit

  ' Release the memory of object variable
  Set OutlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This is of course raw VBA within the Excel file. I'm sure someone more experienced with c# could help you with how to translate this to your server application, or maybe you can store the VBA code in  your excel file and call the sub from your console code..?

Comment: Thanks for your input! :-)